# Fantasy series about a world with ice ships and lots of religious overtones

Tags: story-identification

I've looked for this series several times over the years, but could never find it. I read it in 1988 or 1989 when I was at summer camp.

The only things I remember are there were ice ships that traveled across the world and there was a religious order that was clearly the bad guys in the story. I also assume it was in the style of epic fantasy since that was all I was reading at the time.

Answer (score 9):

I believe you're thinking of the [Ice Prophet trilogy](https://tinyurl.com/ycfrgsk9) by [William R. Forstchen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_R._Forstchen#Ice_Prophet_series).

1980s, check.  Ice ships, check.  Religious overtones, check. :-)

From Amazon's summary:

> Then, unexpectedly, a hero emerged and offered hope to the oppressed. With great ice fleets, he conquered the forces of tyranny and brought the promise of renewal to an otherwise miserable world. But nothing was quite as it seemed -- either to Michael Ormson or to his followers.

Comment: Link seems broken.

Comment: @FakeName, thanks; [seems that SO is mangling Amazon links](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11065/5930) for some reason.  I've replaced it with a Goodreads link.

Comment: (I've now put the original link back, using a URL shortener [as suggested by Valorum](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11066/5930).)

Answer (score 5):

There's a light probability that it's actually the low-tech Science Fiction series from Alan Dean Foster that starts with the book
 [*Icerigger*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icerigger).

[image: cover]

> After an unfortunate accident, Ethan Fortune, a simple salesman and sophisticated interstellar traveler, finds himself stranded on the deadly frozen world of Trần-Ky-Ky with professional adventurer Skua September. Together they search for a way off the planet while fighting against both the extreme weather and deadly fauna of the alien world.
>   <sub>-[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icerigger)</sub>

Comment: Why do you think this is the case? A synopsis and a cover image would be helpful ;)

Comment: That book brings back memories ... one of the only books I read twice as a child :-)

Comment: Loved that book, one of his best. Doubt it's the answer though.

Answer (score 4):

It could be *The Ice Schooner*, by Michael Moorcock.

Per [GoodReads](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/60157.The_Ice_Schooner):

> The world lay frozen under a thousand feet of ice -- and only in the Eight Cities of the Matto Grosso did men still live, hunting the wary ice whales for meat and oil, following the creed of the Ice Mother which foretold the end of all life in ultimate cold.
>   But legend told of a city far to the north -- fabled New York -- whose towers rose above the ice, whose crypts held the forgotten lore that might bring warmth to Earth once again.
>   And, in the best ice ship in the Eight Cities, Konrad Arflane embarked on the impossible voyage to New York -- an odyssey of incredible peril and adventure... with a shattering discovery at journey's end

A major theme is the conflict between the Ice Mother religion and the growing minority who are taking a more scientific approach and realize that the climate is slowly warming.  The protagonist, Konrad Arflane, is initially on the religious side (although he admits that he is not really that devout; the one truly devoted follower of the Ice Mother is a ice whaler who keeps talking about destiny).  However, over the course of the journey up from Brazil to study frozen New York, Arflane comes to realize that the scientists are right, although, in the end, he cannot accept that for himself.